# How to find number of items which falls in a specific range in a column of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, tidyr

I have the following data frame:

```
id weekly_sale
1    40000
2    120000
3    135000
4    211000
5    215000
6    331000
7    337000
```

and i have the following ranges:

```
under 100000
between 100000 and 200000
between 200000 and 300000
more than 300000
```

they can be seen as a vector :

```
c(0,100000,200000,300000)
```

I need to count the the values that fall into each range and result a data frame like this:

```
 under_100000   between_100000_and_200000  between_200000_and_300000   more_than_300000
 1                   2                       2                          2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the grouping and then with `table` get the frequency.

```
 with(df1, table(cut(weekly_sale, breaks = c(-Inf,100000, 200000, 
         300000, Inf), labels = c("under 100000", "between 100000 and 200000", 
           "between 200000 and 300000", "more than 300000"))))
 # under 100000 between 100000 and 200000 between 200000 and 300000          more than 300000 
     1                               2                              2                         2
```